# SonarQube: Saving the number of incoming dependencies as metric

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube provides a great tool *Dependencies* with all known versions of a project and the projects the versions are used by.

I want to save the number of projects a project is used by as a metric. It's useful to see if the project is used by X projects and the diffences between versions.

Overall usage of ALL versions would be enough, but detailed information about every known version whould be useful as well.

Is there a way to access this information during analysis and save it as metric? Sensor/Decorator?

We found **DecoratorContext** and the methods **getIncomingDependencies** and **getOutgoingDependencies**, but **getIncomingDependencies** returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

due to the following Jira ticket (http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553), I would discourage you from investing some time to develop this feature.

Comment: Does this mean "Libraries" and "Dependencies" tools will be dropped as well in the future???

Comment: Okay... Found this "Features like Libraries or Dependencies do not directly relate to source code analysis, so there's no real reason why we should keep them" Still, any advice how I can currently solve this? It's needed!

Comment: Feel free to try asking this development question to the SonarQube Google group :https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube